# A sample to queue network packets with NF_QUEUE in NetFilter

Tags: network-protocols, kernel-module, netfilter

Do you have a sample code about how to implement a filter to send the packets to a queue by returning NF_QUEUE in NetFilter as a kernel module? I'm searching for more than an hour just or a complete example but couldn't find yet.

I found an example but It mentions about a problem in it : http://us.generation-nt.com/queuing-pkts-using-nf-queue-handler-bridge-pf-bridge-mode-not-working-2-6-kernel-help-184087311.html

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good place to get all these information from:
http://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/doxygen/